# I am working on my first tkinter project and i need some guidance

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I've uploaded the entire code. The problem is on entering a non integer in the field, the program halts and it force quits. I tried solving it by using the part of code I've commented out. My solution doesn't work, so any guidance would be helpful.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def sarteg():
    **#while True:
    #    try:
    #        a= int(e.get())
    #    except ValueError:
    #        eror= Label(root,text="Please enter an integer").pack()
    #        continue
    #    else:
    #        break**
    a= int(e.get())
    if a%2==0:
        even=Label(root,text="number is even").pack()
    else:
        odd=Label(root,text="number is odd").pack()
label1= Label(root, text="Enter an Integer then click on \"FIND OUT\"").pack()
e = Entry(root, width=20)
e.pack()

mybutt= Button(root, text="find out", command=sarteg)
mybutt.pack()
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code, it seems to working fine.
You had error on line 5.
You added 2 asterisks.

```
    **#while True:
```

If you remove the asterisks, it's working fine. Comments can be added by just adding `#` before the line.

One more thing I'd recommend it to create a common `label` to show the results. Because every time you check the number a new label appears creating a list of results.

Comment: The code doesn't work fine for me, as the function contains a while true loop so the program stalls

Comment: @RolvApneseth I did not consider it part of the code as it was part of the comments. But it can be functional. There is no need of `while` loop there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you really have to do is remove the while True statement. Try this:

```
def sarteg():
    try:
        a = int(e.get())
    except ValueError:
        eror = Label(root, text="Please enter an integer").pack()
        return None
    if a % 2 == 0:
        even = Label(root, text="number is even").pack()
    else:
        odd = Label(root, text="number is odd").pack()
```

Comment: I see. I did not realise that in Graphical UI the program is already looping so there was no need for that "while true" loop. Thanks very much!